# Mysql part-match search algorithm

Tags: mysql

Im going to make a search field, where the user types the item he/she is looking for.

lets say `helm` in this example.

The database holds items, like:

```
id | name | 
1 | helm of c
2 | helm of 9
3 | helm 
4 | helmset
5 | helmapo
6 | haloween
```

how can i make the mysql query in this case return row 1-5, cause its all match?

Answer (score 2):

You can use wildcards

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%helm%'
```

More information on wildcards: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Comment: @rahultripathu Because the user did not specify that users would only be looking for words/strings that begin with helm. %helm% allows for helm to be in any position in the string

Comment: Then you can add that explicitly. It will make your answer more clear :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make wildcard search like this:

```
select * from tablename where name like 'helm%'
```

Also if you the word `helm` can appear in the middle of the column value or any place then put it like

```
select * from tablename where name like '%helm%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sql wildcards to handle this use case

```
SELECT row FROM tablename WHERE field LIKE '%helm%'
```

If you encapsulate the search term with % on both sides the SQL will return any row containing the search term at any index position, however if you only want return rows that start with helm then you would use the term

```
'helm%'
```